# Poker Dice - Full house vs Two pairs Probabilities

Tags: probability

I have a problem working why these two different probabilities are calculated slightly differently.

> 5 dice are rolled simultaneously.
>   Work out:
>
> 1. $P(\text{two pairs})$
> 2. $P(\text{full house})$

For two pairs, the working commonly shown is:
AABBC 
Two different values in 6 * possible values of last die * ways to position first pair * ways to position second pair / total outcomes:
$${6 \choose 2} \cdot 4 \cdot {5 \choose 2}\cdot {3\choose 2} \cdot \frac{1}{6^5}$$

So I would expect the calculation for the full house to be: 
two different values in 6 * ways to position triple * ways to position pair / total outcomes:
$$ {6\choose 2}  \cdot {5\choose 3}\cdot {2\choose 2}\cdot \frac{1}{6^5}$$

This incorrect way of working it out gives me exactly half the expected answer.

Does it have something to do with the pairs being the same whereas a pair and triple is different? If it does why does that matter? Can you give an intuitive explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly correct, since triples are different then pairs, you need to differentiate $AAABB$ from $AABBB$, so you need to choose which one of the values is your triple. So your calculation should be: Choose a number to be the triple (6), Choose a number to be the pair (5), Ordenate them 5C3*2C2, which differs from your calculation exactly by the factor of two inclueded in 6C2.